# Nuget Package is not including self as a dependency

Tags: c#, nuget, generator, t4, nuspec

I'm creating a nuget package out of a class library.  I have explicit includes for files which works fine, but my dll is not being included in the package.  It was my impression that a nuget package by default would include itself as a dll in the package I could be mistaken. My nuspec file looks like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <package >
    <metadata>
      <id>DTOCodeGenerator</id>
      <version>1.0.0.1</version>
      <title>DTO Code Generator</title>
      <authors>Short Circuit</authors>
      <owners>J5</owners>
      <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
      <description>DTO Code Generator Includes the needed include tt files to generate interface backed DTO's with adapter generation</description>
      <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
      <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
      <tags>DTOGenerator T4</tags>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency id="EntireOne.Shared.T4" version="2.0.10.24" />
      </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
      <file src="T4Generators\AutoMapperExtensions.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\AutoMapperExtensions.ttinclude"/>
      <file src="T4Generators\ConstGenerator.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\ConstGenerator.ttinclude"/>
      <file src="T4Generators\DTOGenerator.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\DTOGenerator.ttinclude"/>
      <file src="T4Generators\EnumGenerator.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\EnumGenerator.ttinclude"/>
    </files>
  </package>
```

how can I add my current dll into the nuget package

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#excluding-development-dependencies-when-creating-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone else is wondering all you have to do is add another line to the files and reference your dll like so:

```
<file src="bin\Debug\DTOCodeGenerator.dll" target="lib"/>
```